# Image upload, resize and store vue js firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue js and firebase for my SPA app. I want to upload image, resize it to fixed dimension and upload it to firebase.

I'm using **Jimp** npm package to resize the uploaded image.

Below is my code:

**Main.js**

```
import Jimp from 'jimp';
Window.Jimp = Jimp;
```

Snippet that handle upload image

```
    uploadImage(e) {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    Jimp.read(file)
      .then(lenna => {
        return lenna
          .resize(256, 256) // resize
          .quality(60) // set JPEG quality
          .write(file.name); // save
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
      conslole.log(lenna);
    var storageRef = fb.storage().ref("products/" + file.name);

    let uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      snapshot => {},
      error => {},
      () => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
          this.product.images.push(downloadURL);
          console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

With the above code I get the following error message:

**No matching constructor overloading was found. Please see the docs for how to call the Jimp constructor.**

Can anyone help me to figure out the mistake I'm making here ?

Answer (score 0):

first create buffer, then pass the created buffer to `jimp.read()`:

```
const imageBuffer = new Buffer.from(image, 'base64');
const jimpImgBuffProm = await Jimp.read(imageBuffer);
```